# Why delegate event show NullReferenceException?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I follow the tutorial write the code ,but still show this error,the script already attach to the game object
[image: Gamecontroller]

[image: GameUI]

[image: Error]

Comment: Do not post images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue caused by the Execution Order of Event Functions.

When I checked logs, `OnEnable` of `GameUI` was called before `Awake` of `GameController`.
So, `GameController.instance` is null when you access `GameController.instance.OnGameInfoChanged` in `void OnEnable()` in GameUI.cs.

In [Unity Manual for Execution Order of Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), it says `Awake` is before `OnEnable`, I guess it doesn't guarantee always.

So, I think you'd better to modify GameUI.cs like below.

```
public class GameUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timeLabel;

    private bool isInitialized = false;

    void Start()
    {
        isInitialized = true;
        GameController.instance.OnGameInfoChanged += this.OnGameInfoChanged;
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (isInitialized)
            GameController.instance.OnGameInfoChanged += this.OnGameInfoChanged;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        GameController.instance.OnGameInfoChanged -= this.OnGameInfoChanged;
    }

    void OnGameInfoChanged(GameType type)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tested your code in my workspace, I added some code for printing log at `OnEnable` of `GameUI` and `Awake` of `GameController`. If you want to see logs, you can add like `Debug.Log("msg");`

Comment: i moved OnEnable code to Start method,it works,thank you!